# Unbinding a name referenced by an enclosing scope

Tags: python, syntax-error, unbind

From the Python Language Reference (v 3.1, see here - http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding ):

> It is illegal to unbind a name referenced by an enclosing scope; the compiler will report a SyntaxError.

But when I run the following code:

```
a = 3

def x():
  global a
  del(a)

print(a)
x()
```

it works fine; and when I change the order of calls:

```
x()
print(a)
```

I get a NameError, not a SyntaxError. Apparently, I'm not understanding the rule correctly. Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to where you quote? This page says a NameError should be raised: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement

Comment: @carl: Took me a few to find it too; several paragraphs into http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding.

Comment: Added the link to the appropriate section of the language reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the people on python-devel list and here is what I got:

> Actually you can do that now 3.2+. I've now removed that sentence.

So, actually it was sort of a documentation error.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that rule applies to the global scope. The global scope is always fully accessible.

Here's an example:

```
>>> def outer():
...     a=5
...     def inner():
...         nonlocal a
...         print(a)
...         del a
...
SyntaxError: can not delete variable 'a' referenced in nested scope
```